# Two dimentional array not initializing properly in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a comma separated string that needs to be split into two dimentional array. I'm creating that array like this:

```
String str = "-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-";
String [] arr = str.split(",");
String [][] 2dArr = new String[8][4];

int j = 0;
int z = 0;
for(int i=0; i!=32; i++){
    Log.i("loop vars", String.valueOf(i)+" "+String.valueOf(j)+" "+String.valueOf(z));
    2dArr[z][j] = arr[i];
    j++;
    z++;
    if(j==4){j=0;}
    if(z==8){z=0;}

}
```

But when I print it:

```
for (String [] a : 2dArr) {
    Log.i("Array in 2dArr", Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

The array looks like this:

```
[-, null, null, null]
[null, -, null, null]
[null, null, -, null]
[null, null, null, -]
[-, null, null, null]
[null, -, null, null]
[null, null, -, null]
[null, null, null, -]
```

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that you have is in here:

```
for(int i=0; i!=32; i++){
    Log.i("loop vars", String.valueOf(i)+" "+String.valueOf(j)+" "+String.valueOf(z));
    2dArr[z][j] = arr[i];
    j++;
    z++;
    if(j==4){j=0;}
    if(z==8){z=0;}
}
```

You're incrementing both `j` and `z`, they get initialized to `0` and every loop you will incrementing this value by 1. That is why your output is coming out diagonally.

What you want to be doing is incrementing `z` every time, and once you get to the end of your row, increment `j`.

Using your array initialization as an example `String [][] 2dArr = new String[8][4];`

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        // add element into the column
    }
    // inserted into the last column, now we will update the row and continue
}
```

EDIT: I recommend not using `8` and `4` as hard coded values here, but actually getting the length of the array instead. But since it seems you are a beginner I used these hardcoded to make the example more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the row and column with every single iteration of the for loop. You only want to change the row when you reach the end of the columns for that row.

Remove the `z++` you currently have, as well as the `if (z==8)` part because `z` will never get that high in this case, and change the `if (j==4)` part to `if(j == 4) { j=0; z++; }`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    Log.i("loop vars", String.valueOf(i) + " " + String.valueOf(j) + " " + String.valueOf(z));
    2dArr[z][j] = arr[i];
    j++;
    if (j == 4) {
        j = 0;
        z++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```
 int count = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < 8, i++){
     for(int j = 0; i < 4, j++){
          2dArr[i][j] = arr[count];
          count++; 
       }
  }
```

And then simply printout the 2d array with similar for loop shown above.